# How to send mail using Httpclient 4.x

Tags: java, outlook, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am creating a library for outlook connector with java HttpClient 4.x.. i have to send mail  from my application. i am able to put the message in draft folder. but how can i send to recepient. here is the code which i have tried`

```
    String strTempURI = "https://" + serverName + "/exchange/" + Username
            + "/drafts/" +strSubject + "eml";
    String strSubURI = "https://" + serverName + "/exchange/" + Username
            + "/##DavMailSubmissionURI##/";

    URI uri=new URI(strTempURI);
    HttpPut put = new HttpPut(uri);
    ByteArrayEntity entity = new ByteArrayEntity(byteout1);
    DefaultHttpClient client =new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST,    
                  AuthScope.ANY_PORT,AuthScope.ANY_REALM, AuthPolicy.BASIC),
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials(Username, password));

   client.setCredentialsProvider(credsProvider);
   put.setHeader("Content-Type", "message/rfc822");
   put.setEntity(entity);
   localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.CREDS_PROVIDER, credsProvider);
   HttpResponse response=client.execute(put,localContext);
   HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
   String result = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
```

"byteout1" contains the mail content. After client.execute() i want to move the content to "strSubURI"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is Answer for My question. juts Create an MoveMethod(sourceurl,desturl) Using

```
String strTempURI = "https://" + serverName + "/exchange/" + Username
        + "/drafts/" +strSubject + "eml";
String strSubURI = "https://" + serverName + "/exchange/" + Username
        + "/##DavMailSubmissionURI##/";

URI uri=new URI(strTempURI);
HttpPut put = new HttpPut(uri);
ByteArrayEntity entity = new ByteArrayEntity(byteout1);
DefaultHttpClient client =new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST,    
              AuthScope.ANY_PORT,AuthScope.ANY_REALM, AuthPolicy.BASIC),
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials(Username, password));

client.setCredentialsProvider(credsProvider);
put.setHeader("Content-Type", "message/rfc822");
put.setEntity(entity);
localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.CREDS_PROVIDER, credsProvider);
HttpResponse response=client.execute(put,localContext);
HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
String result = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);

 MoveMethod move = new MoveMethod(uri.toString(), strSubURI);
        move.setHeader("Destination", strSubURI);
        HttpResponse status = client.execute(move);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need WebDAV support to execute the MOVE , checkout [Jackrabbit](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/jackrabbit-webdav-library.html)